# Are both of these indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

**Scenario 1:**

$$f(x):=\int{\cos(x)dx}\tag{1}$$

**Scenario 2:**

$$g(x):=\int_{a}^{x}{\cos(t)dt}\tag{2}\\ [\text{edited after seeing @hardmath's comment}]\\ [\text{a is a constant}]$$

**Comments:**

Both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are functions. An antiderivative/indefinite integral is a function, while a definite integral is a number. So,

$$f(x)=g(x)=\sin(x)+c\tag{3}\\ [\text{c is a constant}]$$

Is line $(3)$ correct? Are both $(1)$ & $(2)$ antiderivatives/indefinite integrals?

Comment: (2) should be $\int_a^x\cos(t)dt$.

Comment: Your second integral is an "abuse of notation" because the variable $x$ that appears inside the integral gets reused as a *limit of integration* (and as the argument to $g(x)$).  It is better to replace the variable of integration with a "dummy variable" such as:  $$ g(x) := \int_a^x \cos(t) \mathrm{d}t $$

Comment: @hardmath yes you're right sir; my bad, should I edit to correct it?

Comment: No, I just wanted to comment (or as some might say, "nitpick").  I think the Question makes sense, and it got a good Answer from Greg.  I hope you saw the (closely) Related link (shown to the right on the desktop site): [Textbooks that use notation ... for "indefinite integrals."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299028/textbooks-that-use-notation-with-explicit-argument-variable-in-the-upper-bound)

Comment: @hardmath Sir, I'm confused about this question still, so I posted another [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4353840/768162). If you want, you can check it out.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite. (1) is definitely (no pun intended) an indefinite integral. Note that evaluating an indefinite integral does not actually lead to a function, but rather to a family of functions differing by a constant. In the case of (1), we have $f(x) = \sin x + C$ (a family of functions).

(2) is simply a function for any given $a$: by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $g(x) = \sin x - \sin a$. Note that this really is one function, not a family of functions. (If one takes a family of parameters $a$, then that would result in a family of functions $g(x) = g_a(x)$; but it still wouldn't result in every possible function in the family from (1), since $\sin a$ is bounded.)

Comment: I see. I had this concept from an earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4352235/768162). Please see EricTowers' 2nd comment kind sir. It seems like you are disagreeing with him. I'm confused.

Comment: A definite integral can have constants as endpoints, in which case it results in a numerical answer, or it can have variables as endpoints, in which case it results in an answer that is a function of those variables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification kind sir. I had another question: $\int{\cos xdx}=\sin x+c$. $\sin x+c$ is an anti-derivative/indefinite integral. Now, c is a constant, and it could have any of the following values $c=\pi, \frac{1}{3}, 4, 5,3,-3,...$. Now, if I specify the value of $c$ ($c=3$ for example), will $\sin x+3$ still be called an indefinite integral?

Comment: "Antiderivative" and "indefinite integral" are not synonyms. An indefinite integral is literally an integral, and evaluating an indefinite integral leads to the set of all antiderivatives of the integrand (the set of all functions whose derivative equals the integrand). So: $\int \cos x\,dx$ is an indefinite integral; $\sin x + C$ is the set of all antiderivatives of $\cos x$; and $\sin x + 3$ is one antiderivative of $\cos x$.

Comment: Sir, I posted another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4353840/768162) related to your answer. If you want, you can check it out.

Comment: @GregMartin With all due respect, you are wrong. "Antiderivatives" and "indefinite integrals" are synonymous, and they are certainly treated as synonymous by every calculus instructor I know of, and by plenty of textbooks, as well. But leaving aside the fact that "indefinite integral" is not even legitimate mathematical terminology (no mathematician uses such terminology, it is only used by educational calculus sources), let me ask you: in what sense is an indefinite integral "literally an integral"? Is it a Riemann integral? Is it a Lebesgue integral? What is it, exactly?

Comment: You have now met a calculus instructor who does not treat them as synonymous. Note that I would never fault a student who used those terms interchangeably in practice—but the OP has asked several questions about fine distinctions in the terminology. $\sin x+C$ is not an indefinite integral—it's not an integral of any sort. $\int \cos x\,dx$ is not an antiderivative—it's not a function of any sort. By the way, your claim that "indefinite integral" is not legitimate mathematical terminology and that no mathematican uses it is demonstrably false.

Comment: @GregMartin Sir, is $f(x)=\sin(x)+C$ the parent function of the family of functions?